# How to append items to a list in a parallel process (python-asyncio)?

Tags: python, list, python-asyncio

I have a function which adds items to the list and returns the list. The items are returned from async function. Now it creates the item and then adds it one by one.

I want to create the items in parallel and add them to the list and after that return the value of the function. How can I solve this?

Thank you in advance!

```
    async def __create_sockets(self):
        rd_data = []
        for s in self.symbols.index:
            try:
                print(f'Collecting data of {s}')
                socket = DepthCacheManager(self.client, s, refresh_interval=None)
                rd_data.append(await socket.__aenter__())
            except:
                continue
        return rd_data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution to your problem is to gather the results asynchronously and compile the list of results at the same time.

This is provided by the `asyncio.gather()` call [as explained in the asyncio documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently). Have a look at the excellent example given there.

In your case it might roughly look like this (obviously I cannot test it):

```py
async def create_socket(self, s):
    print(f'Collecting data of {s}')
    socket = DepthCacheManager(self.client, s, refresh_interval=None)
    return socket.__aenter__()

async def __create_sockets(self):
    rd_data = await asyncio.gather(
        *[self.create_socket(s) for s in self.symbols.index]
    )
    return rd_data
```

There is a problem here with missing exception handling. You may return None in case of an exception and then clean up the list later like this:

```py
async def create_socket(self, s):
    try:
        print(f'Collecting data of {s}')
        socket = DepthCacheManager(self.client, s, refresh_interval=None)
        return await socket.__aenter__() # await is important here
    except:
        return None

async def __create_sockets(self):
    rd_data = await asyncio.gather(
        *[self.create_socket(s) for s in self.symbols.index]
    )
    return [i for i in rd_data if i != None]
```